# How does this site slide its newsletter+ from the top?

Tags: jquery, css, newsletter, superfish

Trying to figure out how this site makes their newsletter+ button makes the page slide down:

http://thestoryoftelling.com/ (click on "newsletter+")

It looks like the #wrap element has the page offset by 57px and it's background url effectively becomes the background for the signup link after "sliding" in. Clicking on "newsletter+" calls a "_gaq" function, but that seems to be more for tracking.

I'm thinking it's activated via superfish, but I don't understand how or where this gets called from:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('#header .menu, .superfish').superfish({
        delay:       100,                               // 0.1 second delay on mouseout 
        animation:   {opacity:'show',height:'show'},    // fade-in and slide-down animation 
        dropShadows: false                              // disable drop shadows 
    });
});
```

Any ideas out there? Probably a jquery thing.

Comment: Try to open it and then close it via a double click. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, personally I'd do something like that by having the coloured bar be the first element on the page, and give it a negative `margin-top` so only the bottom edge shows. Then I can set `style.marginTop='0'` and if I have suitable `transition` properties set then it will slide exactly like the website you show.

[Demonstration on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuGEG/)

Comment: thank you! follow up question - if the page has a background image it appears to not scroll with the content, is there a way around this and/or maybe i implemented it incorrectly?